# Less compiler on Windows 7

Tags: compiler-errors, less, phpstorm

I try tu use less compiler on Windows 7. I installed **node.js** and **less** with right commands.

I work on Phpstorm and I tried to add the Less watcher. It failed.

```
An exception occurred while executing watcher 'LESS'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it. Cannot run program "Path/to/lessc" (in directory "Path/to/css/directory"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

So, last chance, I tried to compile with the command

```
lessc my-css.less > my-css.css /  lessc.cmd my-css.less > my-css.css
```

The result is weird:

```
ParseError: directive options not recognised in 'Path/to/my/less/file'
```

When I try to add the extension for the cmd, the result is:

```
/c/Users/blabla/AppData/Roaming/npm/lessc.cmd: line 1: syntax error nearunexpected token `('/c/Users/blabla/AppData/Roaming/npm/lessc.cmd: line 1:`@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" ('
```

Any idea about the reason ? I'm a bit lost...

The code which seems to generate the error is:

```
@widthsite = 100%;
@maincolor1 = #1f2b54; // purple
@maincolor1-5 = #6f7792; // light purple
@maincolor2 = #809a56; // green
@maincolor3 = #9c9b9b; // grey
@maincolor4 = #e0e0e0; // grey2
```

Comment: "directive options not recognised in" - so what is the code in that less file after all? As for the Phpstorm error, it looks like you just did not specified the proper path to the `lessc` in the watcher settings. Not that in Windows `lessc` command refers to the `lessc.cmd` script.

Comment: I changed the path to my less file for the watcher. Now i've the same error on phpstorm and with the cmd, so I guess it's a progress haha.

The error is still ' ParseError: directive options not recognised in 'Path/to/my/less/file '

Comment: "The error is still ' ParseError: directive options not recognised in ..." - as I mentioned above it just means the file you compile has invalid Less code. We won't be able to say what the error is until you actually show the code to us.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my post with the code which seems to generate the error

Comment: The error is in `=`. Less syntax for defining variables is `@name: value;`.

Comment: Feeling a bit ashamed right now. The solution was in front of my nose...
Thank you very much, it works !